# An efficient algorithm to find Nearest Neighbours

Tags: algorithms, performance

So imagine I have a $m$ vectors each of dimension $d$. Lets call them, $\vec x_{i}$, with $i = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, \dots, m$. Now the idea is to find the neighbours of $\vec x_{i}$ (calling them $\vec x_{j}$), within a ball of radius $r$. So, $$ || \vec x_{i} - \vec x_{j} || \le r$$.

Note: $|| \cdots ||$ is the Euclidean norm.

Naively one can compute distance between all the $j$'s for a particular $i$, and then sort them, and keep only the elements which are less than $r$. This is computationally expensive for large $m$ and $d$.

> So the question is how can I efficiently compute the neighbours $x_{j}$?

Comment: For small $d$, KD-trees work pretty well. For example scipy has [this function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.html) that does exactly what you want. There are even better data structures like range trees and ball trees that reduce the worst-case complexity. But you mention large $d$ and, as far as I know, developing spatial data structures that work well in high-dimensional space is very much an unsolved problem. For example KD-trees fall on their face pretty quick for large $d$.

Comment: @DanielShapero: How good is the performance for $d \approx 20$? I did have a look at this function, but I'm not well verse in trees.

Comment: In my experience, even for a moderately sized $d$ (20 is pushing the limit), the cost of building the tree and performing a query can be relatively inexpensive relative to the cost of one brute-force nearest neighbor query. I'm sure @DanielShapero is correct in general, but you never know until you try it on your data set.

Comment: @CharlieS is absolutely right, experimentation is more valuable than the advice of strangers on the internet :D

Comment: Thanks for the headsup. I'm running some benchmarks. Let's see!

Comment: @DanielShapero: A small query. KDTree.query_ball_point(...), returns the indices of the NN. But these are not ordered according to its distance (Euclidean here). Any sleight of hand to get this in that order? I actually need it in that fashion for my subsequent computation?

Comment: If the k-d tree doesn't work for you, remember that the brute force nearest neighbor search is very easy to parallelize. Also, since calculating the distance for your $d$ is quite involved, you might be able to shave off a few milliseconds by looking at the first few coordinates to see if those alone render the point outside the ball. For example, I know the point $(1000,1.2,-3.1)$ is more than 10 units away from the origin just by looking at the first coordinate. Perhaps this tactic can be used to screen points for a more sophisticated query.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that you can get away with a subset of the information by making use of the fact that
$$
  \|x_i-x_j\| = \|x_i-x_k+x_k-x_j\| \ge \|x_i-x_k\| - \|x_k-x_j\|.
$$
You can use this in the following way: Say, you want $r=1$. If $x_1$ and $x_2$ are four units away (not neighbors), and $x_2$ and $x_3$ are one unit away, then $x_1$ and $x_3$ are at least three units away -- also not neighbors. I didn't need to compute the distance between $x_1$ and $x_3$ to determine that.

What this means is that it is possible to use this "reverse triangle inequality" to determine neighborship by knowing only a subset of the entries of the distance matrix
$$
  D_{ij} = \|x_i-x_j\|.
$$
The question is: What subset do you need to know to make all determinations? I would not be very surprised if the algorithm to determine the *minimal* subset is NP, but one could probably come up with a cheaper algorithm that, starting from some subset of entries of $D_{ij}$ determines which entries do *not* need to be computed, then computes some of the other currently unknown ones, and iterates that until for every entry of $D$ you've either computed its value, or determined that you don't need it.